Is it valid to `static_assert(false)` after handling all variant types in a visitor?
An example on cppreference.com includes the following:
...

// the variant to visit
using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;

...

int main()
{
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {10, 15l, 1.5, "hello"};
 
    for (auto& v: vec)
    {
        ...
        var_t w = ...
        ...
        std::visit([](auto&& arg)
        {
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
                std::cout << "int with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)
                std::cout << "long with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
                std::cout << "double with value " << arg << '\n';
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
                std::cout << "std::string with value " << std::quoted(arg) << '\n';
            else 
                static_assert(false, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
        }, w);
    }
    ...
}

This kind of thing does not work in my version of GCC (“static assertion failed”). By copy-pasting the example into Compiler Explorer, I was able to quickly figure out that this only causes an error pre-GCC 13.1. So it was a bug in GCC that got fixed? The latest versions of some other compilers still produce an error. According to the standard, should this code compile or not? (And if yes, how likely is it that the other compiler vendors are going to bother fixing their compilers? Is this a relevant idiom?)

It's only valid in C++23. Before that you should use a workaround, otherwise your code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Actually, I'm not sure anymore. cppreference states that this paper was accepted as defect all the way back to C++11, but I don't see anything in standard website to confirm that.

@Yksisarvinen It says "[Accepted as a DR at the February, 2023 meeting.]" at the top. You'll probably find the voting results in some meeting minutes from that time. The "Status: C++23" at the top only refers to the first (i.e. next) revision that will include the changes officially.

@user17732522 Well, GitHub has this about P2593: https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1251 and this about CWG2518: https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1366 (which is the CWG where P2593 was eventually merged). Neither seems to mention anything but C++23. I really wish standard had some clear way of telling which DR was applied retroactively to which standard.
